# RunDLL error Hard Disk Drive

Tags: rundll

I can't open my hard disk drive. The error box says

> "RUnDLL, there was a problem starting ~$WCFLPM.FAT32 The specified
>   module could not be found".

My HDD has a virus before. My hard disk contains a shortcut and the shortcut contains all files. I don't want to format it just yet because it contains quite many files. I tried troubleshooting it but none of the solutions in the internet helped.

Comment: Have you tried opening it on linux? If it works (and it might) you should be able to get the data out then reformat it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an autorun.inf in root of your hard disk, but after virus infection, maybe that file is system, read-only and hidden. for example if this is your want to access your D: drive use below commands:

```
Attrib -r -s -h d:\autorun.inf
Del /F d:\autorun.inf
```

Answer (score 1):

1. delete all the autorun.inf files from all drives (from windows, or if you want to be safer, use a linux boot CD)
2. open registry and go to the following keys and delete the ones that you know you did'n install:

   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Answer (score 0):

Just open the hard drive then properties of the shortcut then change the directory of the shortcut to G or I or F or anything where your drive letters indicate at my computer you should type like this G:\ then "apply" then click "OK".

You should be able to open your files now.